# WPF LayoutTransform (Scale) throws Exception because DesiredSize of Image is NaN

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, measure, scaletransform

I am setting the ImageSource of an Image like this:

```
Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource,BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
BitmapSource bmSrc = decoder.Frames[0];
bmSrc.Freeze();
ImageSource = bmSrc;
```

The Image uses a ScaleTransform (LayoutTransform) in a Scrollviewer. 
LayoutTransform is needed to update the ScrollViewers content size. 
I want to scale the image to the size of the parent of the scrollviewer (bounds):

```
double horizontalAspectRatio = gridBounds.Width / image.Width;
double verticalAspectRatio = gridBounds.Height / image.Height;

if (horizontalAspectRatio > verticalAspectRatio) {
     scaleTransformImage.ScaleX = scaleTransformImage.ScaleY = verticalAspectRatio;
     MessageBox.Show("to height");
} else {
     scaleTransformImage.ScaleX = scaleTransformImage.ScaleY = horizontalAspectRatio;
     MessageBox.Show("to width");
}
```

After doing that an InvalidOperationException is thrown and it says that measuring the image's layout requires the DesireSize not to be NaN. 
I tried to measure and arrange the image manually like this:

```
image.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
image.Arrange(new Rect(0d, 0d, gridBounds.Width, gridBounds.Height));
```

But it doesn't seem to have an effect.
I am just starting out with Transforms and do not have a lot of knowledge yet....

Comment: Did you set the Image control's Width and Height somewhere? If not, their values are NaN. You should use ActualWidth and ActualHeight in the aspect ratio calculations.

Comment: @Clemens Seems to work now, except the ActualValues (for the scale calc) are not set early enough. That means I have to Measure and Arrange, right? EDIT: ActualValues are 0d...

Comment: When the Source property is already set, you may perhaps also use `image.Source.Width` and `image.Source.Height`.

Comment: @Clemens Works. Wanna post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you did not explicitly set the Image control's `Width` and `Height` properties, their values will be `NaN`, and the aspect ratio calculation will fail:

```
double horizontalAspectRatio = gridBounds.Width / image.Width;
double verticalAspectRatio = gridBounds.Height / image.Height;
```

You may instead use the Image's `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`, or if it is not yet laid out, the `Width` and `Height` of its `Source`:

```
double horizontalAspectRatio = gridBounds.Width / image.Source.Width;
double verticalAspectRatio = gridBounds.Height / image.Source.Height;
```